# Spider Man is not real. How to fake it?

Tags: science-based, society, super-powers, crime

[This question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/38820/turns-out-spider-man-is-real-how-long-until-people-accept-it) got me thinking of a variation.  **How can Spider Man be Hoaxed?**

This is the real world, so no cartoon physics or nonsensical pseudo-science.

Petty criminals are caught. Videos are posted. Forensic evidence is collected.  A secretive group with kickstarter-level funding is orchestrating things to influence people to *beleive* in the Spider Man.

The scenarios might be staged with prepared apparatuses, multiple people behind the scenes, actors in on the hoax, etc. but **real crimes** are stopped and criminals caught.  There may be fake crimes like purse snatchers and baby rescues that are fake videos, but some real crime scenes exist and are investigated by police.

Comment: That's what I meant. Fat-fingered the pop-up.

Comment: I don't see a direct correlation to worldbuilding here. A case could be made for the formation of an organization dedicated to creating hoaxes, but specifically for the formation of Spider Hoax feels too story-bound to be a good fit for the site.

Comment: This isn't really about world building, unless you plan in making an entire race of fake spider mans.

Comment: How's it different from the other question I linked to?  @XandarTheZenon, @youstay?  I'd like to make it more analogous. So it should be just the same topic-ness.

Comment: @Frostfyre I based my answer below on the assumption that Spiderman in this case is an abstraction and not the actual comic book hero - I think this assumption _might_ make the question fit for Worldbuilding SE. (Like "What would it take for a group of individuals with certain possibilities to fake something like this?" I think there are lots of questions like that around here.)

Comment: I'm not sure about the other one, it seems like it may actually be off topic, upon review. @YoustayIgo what are your thoughts?

Comment: I removed my comment, which was already a question, not an objection. @JDługosz Foregoing the fact that you did not answer my question either, apologies for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 3):

**For starters, you'll need a large group of highly-trained athletes/stunts because even to fake Spiderman's abilities, you need extremely good physical condition.**

---

I mean, even if you have the tech to climb the walls of buildings - which is something [achievable](http://www.nanowerk.com/spotlight/spotid=1182.php) - climbing a skyscraper would be an extremely slow and tiring operation which could not be done repeatedly by the same person. I mean your "Spidy" would really be a team. One martial artist in a suit which is preferably made out of [ballistic nylon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballistic_nylon). Reinforced with [kevlar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevlar) on critical points, equipped with a special sort of [nolwep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-lethal_weapon) to mimic web-throwers used as weapons. (This *nolwep* would not be capable to provide fast escape/travel, you would need an extraction team which prepares exit roots while the martial artist fights the thugs.) Equiping a team of hidden snipers with such *nolweps* to provide covering fire is also a presumably good idea.

Climbing walls in a bulletproof suit would not really be an option, your martial artist should hide after a quick leave and a parkour stunt person should do the spectacular leave. This would not really be necessary for anything more than maintaining the illusion. To mimic the travel-by-webshooters effect, you need to apply a few aerialists and a team which preinstalls ropes (because the webshooter technology isn't really available IRL). That makes it... let's say one martial artist, two-three parkour artists, two-three aerialists, at least two snipers and a tech team to install and maintain all necessary equipment. In theory it can be done, but what for?